# "bitcoinjs.ECPubKey.fromHex" not found

Tags: c#, bitcoinjs-lib

Currently I am creating Bitcoin Library in C# that related to my company use cases based on [bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib). I realized the function **ECPubKey.fromHex** written my company source code shown as follows is not found in bitcoinjs library.

```
var ecPubKey = bitcoinjs.ECPubKey.fromHex(key)
```

When I going through bitcoinjs-lib, their CHANGELOG has mentioned as below

```
_added_
- export `ECPair`, a merged replacement for `ECKey`/`ECPubKey`, invalid types will throw via `typeforce`

_removed_
- export `ECPubKey`, use new export `ECPair` instead
```

However, I search through ecpair.js file but **fromHex** function is still not found.

Here is the source code for [ecpair.js](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/src/ecpair.js)

Answer (score 0):

I found it in [version 1.0.2](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/releases/tag/1.0.2) and the function is written there.